# More performant update in MySQL than setting a boolean to an in clause

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I have a `customer` table that has a `customer_id` column and a `has_orders` column among others. Let's also assume I have an `order` table that has a `customer_id` column referencing customers in the `customer` table.

If I want to update the `has_orders` column, I can run the following statement:

```
update customer set has_orders = customer_id in (select customer_id from order)
```

This works. However, it's slow, even though I have indexes on `customer_id` in both tables. Is there another update statement (e.g. using joins) that can be faster?

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Are the `customer_id` values in `order` distinct or are there duplicates?

Comment: @RickJames millions. A customer_id can be associated with many orders.

Comment: Then, the Answer suggesting `EXISTS` may speed up the `IN` clause, but fail to help with the `UPDATE`; the `JOIN` answer helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

An index on `customer_id` in the `order` table should already be pretty optimal.  You could write your update using exists instead:

```sql
UPDATE customer c
SET has_orders = EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order o WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id);
```

The possible advantage of the above versus using `IN` is that `EXISTS` will stop as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: Much better, but a trigger is the weapon of choice here.

Comment: No worries, although I might [have the edge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527848/256196) on you this time :)

Comment: In my use case, this is actually slower than my update statement.

Comment: That Update is not the same.  The original only turns ON the flag; this can turn the flag OFF.  (Maybe that is what the OP really needed?!)

Answer (score 1):

If `has_orders` is defined as `boolean not null default false` (a good choice), and orders can never be deleted (likely), update using a join:

```
update orders o
join customer c on c.id = o.customer_id
set has_orders = true
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a9186/1).

If order *can* be deleted (unlikely), update using an outer join, although this will be slower:

```
update customer c
left join `order` o on o.customer_id = c.id
set has_orders = o.customer_id is not null
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7aceb3/1).

---

Side note: If possible, prefer not naming tables/columns with reserved words, such as `order`, because it can require inconvenient delimiting with back-ticks to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: In my use case, this is slower than my update statement.

Comment: The table names are just examples. I didn't use my actual table/column names.

Comment: @stepanian I've modified my answer to speed it up. Try the new query in my answer that is *not* a left join.

Comment: the updated query only updates true values, not false.

Comment: @stepanian it's not meant to update false. If you read my answer, I said *if orders are never deleted*. I put it in the demo link but didn't spell it out that `has_orders` should be defined as `not null` and have a default value of `false`, but I have now in the answer. If you haven't defined it that way, first run `update customer set has_orders = false` then run the update. Also alter the `has_orders` column via `alter table customer modify has_orders boolean not null default false`, which it should be, or always provide `false` for `has_orders` when inserting customer rows.

Comment: I read your answer. Orders not being deleted and updating the has_orders field to false are two separate concerns. Running another update to set the value to false for all records may work, but it leaves the data in the wrong state between the updates. Technically, it can be sent in a batch, but that/s not the approach I would want to take.

Comment: @stepanian if `has_orders` is set to false when the customer row is created, which it should be, everything will be fine. I just gave a few options of how to make it happen, and you haven't shared your schema so I am shooting in the dark.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all your help. Unfortunately, I can't reveal my exact schema for business reasons. What I have is just hypothetical. My schema is significantly different. However, in this particular scenario, I can't assume that the has_orders initially goes in as false and that orders can't be deleted. Therefore, that answer would not work for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you need to update the customer table asynchronously? I guess it might be a poor practice as the integrity of the data can be lost. Moreover this approach breakes normal form idea as the data is duplicated. It seems that a much better way is to retreive the value of `has_orders` selecting the flag (using `exists` statement proposed by @Tim-Biegeleisen or any other) from `order` table on demand and joining it to the dataset from `customers` table.

If the excess column is inevitable i would update it any time upon inserting/updating/deleting the order table and using affected customer `id` only. This can be done in a trigger. It will be rather fast.

Comment: This does not answer the question. My example was hypothetical just to ask about the performance of the update statement. My use case is much more complicated and syncs data from multiple places before running the update.

Comment: @stepanian then the question does not match tre requirements to MCVE.

Comment: @asd-tm - A Trigger has a lot of advantages.  Until you forget it exists.  Then debugging is devilish.

Comment: @stepanian - Sorry.  Sometimes the best solution to a performance question is a re-design.  While I appreciate having the context of what the Update is doing, it did lead most of us into solving the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

A religious war:

- The DB purist would point out that `has_order` is redundant info, hence a no-no.
- The performance fanatic would insist on having (and maintaining) `has_order`

I bring up that debate, not to wage a war, but to point out that getting rid of the flag may be better overall.  When you need the flag, simply do a `LEFT JOIN` or `AND EXISTS(SELECT..)` or some other dynamic test.